# Exposing sash or handle of tkinter.ttk.Panedwindow?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to show the sash/handle of the `ttk.Panedwindow` widget? These options are not available in it stylename (see below).

```
Stylename = TPanedwindow
Layout    = [('Panedwindow.background', {'sticky': ''})]
Element(s) = ['Panedwindow.background']
Panedwindow.background         options: ('background',)
```

[Documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-PanedWindow.html) has described that these options are not support, while they are available in `tk.Panedwindow`. Still, I want to verify its veracity and if anyone knows how to expose the sash/handle of the `ttk.Panewindow` widget?

Comment: If the documentation doesn't say it has a handle, why do you think it does? The [canonical ttk documentation ](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_panedwindow.htm) says nothing about sash options. If you really want to verify the veracity, the best solution is to look in the source code for the ttk panedwindow.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hi. I asked because I think these are useful features that users may want to be able to manipulate, and that other users know a way to do so. For instance, I found from online discussions that in addition to style `Notebook`, there was also a style `TNotebook.Tab` for the `ttk.Notebook` widget; I did not find `TNotebook.Tab` reflected in documentation. Can you tell me where I can find the source code for all the stylename of ttk.Style? I could not find it in `tkinter.ttk`. Cheers.

Comment: The source code will be with the tcl/tk source code. tkinter is just a thin wrapper around tcl, tk, and ttk. ttk is mainly implemented in C and Tcl. You can start your research here: https://core.tcl.tk/tk/dir?ci=tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux distro such as Ubuntu 16.04, I discovered that the `tkinter.ttk.Panedwindow` widget can display a handle between panes. But this appearance only occur when `ttk.Style.theme_use('clam')` is defined. Other style themes, e.g.`'classic'`, `'default'` and `'alt'`, do not display a handle for the panes of the `ttk.Panedwindow` widget.

[image: ttk.Panedwindow with handle]

**Test script:**

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam') #Ubuntu 16.04 using this theme displayed handle btw panes

pw0 = ttk.Panedwindow()
pw0.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

l1 = ttk.Label(pw0, text="pane 1")
l2 = ttk.Label(pw0, text="pane 2")
pw0.add(l1)
pw0.add(l2)

pw0.master.geometry('150x100+100+100')
```